# Excel macro mailmerge - export to pdf

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export, mailmerge

I'm working vba macro which works perfectly but I need save the documents as .pdf.

I´m searching for tips, but I don´t know how to find them. Last time I found this solution : [vba mail merge save as pdf](http://www.computing.net/answers/office/mail-merge-from-excel-to-pdfs-with-specific-naming-of-files/17862.html)
but I don´t know apply it to my macro.

Here is my code:

```
Sub RunMerge()

Dim wd As Object
Dim wdocSource As Object

Dim strWorkbookName As String

On Error Resume Next
Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If wd Is Nothing Then
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wdocSource = wd.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ArtSpecDatabase.docx")

strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name

wdocSource.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

wdocSource.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
        Name:=strWorkbookName, _
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        Revert:=False, _
        Connection:="Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read", _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet2$`"

With wdocSource.MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = 1
        .LastRecord = 1
    End With
    .Execute Pause:=False
End With

Dim PathToSave As String
PathToSave = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "pdf" & "\" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value2 & ".docx"
If Dir(PathToSave, 0) <> vbNullString Then
    wd.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show
Else
    wd.activedocument.SaveAs2 PathToSave, wdFormatDocumentDefault

End If

wd.Visible = True
wdocSource.Close savechanges:=False
wd.activedocument.Close savechanges:=False

Set wdocSource = Nothing
Set wd = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export a Word document as PDF, you need to use the [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.exportasfixedformat.aspx) method. For example, you can replace your SaveAs2 call with this:

```
wd.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat PathToSave, 17 'The constant for wdExportFormatPDF
```

Now, your call to `FileDialog` makes no sense, so I propose changing the entire Dir(...) If-sentence to this:

```
Dim PathToSave As String
PathToSave = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "pdf" & "\" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value2 & ".pdf"
If Dir(PathToSave, 0) <> vbNullString Then
    With wd.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        If .Show = True Then
            PathToSave = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End If

wd.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat PathToSave, 17 'The constant for wdExportFormatPDF
```

EDIT: Forgot to include ".pdf" extension.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your update. I have placed your code to my macro but it doesn´t run. I´m getting run-time error ´5ˇ: Invalid procedure call or argument. After debug this error it shows me bug in code row:
` wd.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat PathToSave, wdExportFormatPDF`

Can you help me what´s wrong?

Comment: Try to replace `wdExportFormatPDF` with 17.

Comment: Great :-) Was a missing constant. Updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to export excel to pdf

```
Sub tst1()

Dim fFilename     As String

    fFilename = "C:\Documents and Settings\test.xlsx"

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
     fFilename & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False


End Sub
```